# What is the respective unicode for delimiter ^_ to be used in scala code?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, unicode

If a record is delimited by  ^A then in my  scala code  i can be use as "\u0001" to fetch each field

```
 val fileLoc         = "/user/cloudera/inputfiles/records.txt"

 val custAccountRDD  =    sc.textFile(fileLoc)

 val splitRDD        =    custAccountRDD.map(elem => elem.split("\\u0001"))
```

I would like what is equivalent delimiter for ^_

sample Input records

```
 4^_123123123^_Any Purchase^_ACTIVE^_1^_DATA^_Published
```

My question is How do I split these records based on the delimiter ^_

I directly tried the below it did not work

```
 val splitRDD        =    custAccountRDD.map(elem => elem.split("^_"))
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Could you be more specific on what output you want for the input `4^_123123123^_Any Purchase^_ACTIVE^_1^_DATA^_Published`? Also about the `^_`: is this a special character or it's just the string "^_"?

Comment: @Dat: ^_ is a delimiter for each record in my input file . This delimiter is called Unit Separator .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
scala> "4^_123123123^_Any Purchase^_ACTIVE^_1^_DATA^_Published".split("\\^\\_")
res5: Array[String] = Array(4, 123123123, Any Purchase, ACTIVE, 1, DATA, Published)
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks much . But is there any other way without using escaping quotes .? something like "\\u0002" or "\\u0003" .. For The delimiter ^A     "\\u0001" works..

Comment: IMO, using "\\^A" is much easier to read than "\\u0001". You're using escaping quote in the "\\u0001" anyway, right? The issue here is that you're having special characters in your string (`^`, `_`, `?`, etc.), and `split()` will be confused because it treats these characters as regex control characters. Using "\\" to escape the regex is actually a correct thing to do, and is much better than trying to come up with special strings such as "\\u0001".

Comment: Ok. Thanks Much . I will use "\\^\\_" for ^_